# Why is my searchBar not resetting to the initial state after the cancel button is clicked?

Tags: swift

I have a ***searchBar*** with a cancel button. When I click on cancel button it doesn't reset the ***searchBar*** to its initial state.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/0trewzFk) is the full source code.

---

```
var searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar()

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        searchBarText = searchBar.text?.lowercased()
        searchBarScope = searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex
        showList()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.text = nil
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    public func setupSearchBarStyle() {
        UISearchBar.appearance().searchBarStyle = .minimal
        UISearchBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UISearchBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        if (navigationItem.title != nil) {
            self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [String(format: "gesamte %@", ci("project_s")),  String(format: "in %@", navigationItem.title!)]
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

        navigationItem.title = navigationItem.title ?? ci("plan_p")

        guard let projectId = GlobalState.selectedProjectId, let byProject : Results<Structure> = self.by(projectId: projectId) else {
            return
        }

        //search bar
        tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.searchBar.delegate = self

        tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

---

How can I change the ***searchBar*** to its initial state after the user clicks on the cancel button? Right now it changes the ***searchText*** to ***nil*** after the user clicks on cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` func:

```
searchBar.text = ""
searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
```

Also in the`textDidChange` :

```
yourSearchBar.showsCancelButton = true
```

Comment: ***searchBar*** does not loose the focus and stays in the selected state with the scope buttons

Comment: @Nimrani1337 Do you mean that when you press cancel the selected scope button is still selected?

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of this code:

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
}
```

It has to be :

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
```